# GCP internal http(s) load balancer timeout after 300s

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Recently, I've a problem with the internal http(s) load balancer on GCP, about the timeout of backend service (an instance group). After 300 seconds, the API calling to LB will be failed with 408 HTTP response.

I have an internal HTTPS load balancer (LB) on GCP.
First, I call a quick API through LB, that worked normally.
Then I set timeout for backend service to 10 seconds then call the slow API (say, 500 seconds to complete the request). The error response happens after 10 seconds as expected.
But when I set the timeout to 1000 seconds and call the slow API, i receive the error timeout response after only exactly 300 seconds.
I also increate the Connection draining timeout to 1000 seconds, but it still doesn't work.

Is the any parameter i need to set to allow API with reply time more than 300 seconds? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [backend service timeout](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#timeout-setting), for HTTP traffic, the maximum amount of time for the client to complete sending its request is equal to the backend service timeout, I’m aware that the suggestion is increase the timeout to avoid the 408 errors, I noticed that your slow app needs more that 300 secs to complete the HTTP request, I reviewed deeper this behavior and based on the GCLB Architecture, the 300 sec timeout that you are seeing is a Stream idle timeout mentioned [here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/filter/network/http_connection_manager/v2/http_connection_manager.proto), please see a recap below:

"request_timeout": ->Backend service timeout --> you have configured 1000 seconds, this ensures that a HTTP request should complete within this timeframe irrespective the connection is not idle and server is sending slow response.

"stream_idle_timeout" : A HTTP stream should not be idle more than this time, even lets say the server sends TCP keepalive but no http response and if the the http stream is idle for 5 minutes, LB closes the connection. This is non configurable currently and default to 5 mins.

idle_timeout: The idle timeout is defined as the period in which there are no active requests. This is 10 minutes.

The behavior that you are seeing seems related of stream_idle_timeout, I kindly recommend you to open a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) in GCP in order to evaluate the possibility to enable the modifying of this value, it's recommended to share all the details and the steps to reproduce the behavior.